# Is it possible to create an auto-increment field in a content type?

Tags: 8

If I am creating a database in MySQL, I can create an auto-increment field for a table.

But is it also possible to create an auto-increment field in a content type in Drupal 8?

Comment: In web everything is possible. Also in Drupal. It always only depends on how much time you wanna invest. Here on Drupal Answers it goes this way: You try it out yourself, get something up and running and when you are stuck you come here and ask a question providing the code or steps that are necessary to understand what you've tried so far. So please update your question.

Answer (score 2):

There is A module called [Serial](https://www.drupal.org/project/serial), for drupal 8 it is in development version but can be downloaded and used, This module provides the same functionality as you desire.

You also can write your own module, you can set a [configuration value](https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/converting-drupal-7-modules-to-drupal-8/step-4-convert-drupal-7-variables-to-drupal-8) in your module, set it to zero by default, and using [hook_ENTITY_TYPE_presave](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Entity%21entity.api.php/function/hook_ENTITY_TYPE_presave/8.2.x), increase its value and set it to your entity.